# Python 3 Protobuf AttributeError from FileDescriptor dependencies list

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I'm compiling protobuf schema files to python 3 using protoc, but after importing via an `__init__.py`'s `__all__`, I'm getting an `AttributeError` from the `dependencies` list of the `FileDescriptor` object. I think my situation is intuitive, but it requires a lengthy description. I have one protobuf schema that imports another one, both in the same package. This almost seems like a circular dependency problem, where the module is not yet initialized before the generated python file tries to reference it.

This is my directory structure, before compilation:

```
company_package
    \ project_package
        \ bar.proto    # imports foo.proto
        \ foo.proto
        \ __init__.py  # exposes classes via __all__
    \ __init__.py      # has extend_path from pkgutil
build.sh
```

with a `build.sh` containing:

```
protoc --python_out=. company_package/project_package/foo.proto
protoc --python_out=. company_package/project_package/bar.proto
```

an independent `foo.proto` containing:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package company;

message Foo {
    required string msg = 1;
}
```

and, as stated above, a dependent `bar.proto` containing:

```
syntax = "proto2";

import "company_package/project_package/foo.proto";

package company;

message Bar {
    required Foo foo = 1;
}
```

The `__init__.py` of `company_package` has the usual `pkgutil.extend_path` code. The `__init__.py` of `project_package` contains:

```
from .foo_pb2 import Foo 
from .bar_pb2 import Bar 


__all__ = ['Foo', 'Bar']
```

After invoking `sh build.sh`, the directory structure is:

```
company_package
    \ project_package
        \ bar_pb2.py
        \ bar.proto
        \ foo_pb2.py
        \ foo.proto
        \ __init__.py
    \ __init__.py
build.sh
```

and if I open up a REPL in an isolated virtual environment and execute the following line, I get this error:

```
In [1]: from company_package.project_package import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-70765a748bd5> in <module>()
----> 1 from company_package.project_package import *

{omitted}/company_package/project_package/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from .foo_pb2 import Foo
----> 2 from .bar_pb2 import Bar
      3~
      4~
      5 __all__ = ['Foo', 'Bar']

{omitted}/company_package/project_package/bar_pb2.py in <module>()
     22   serialized_pb=_b('\n)company_package/project_package/bar.proto\x12\x07\x63ompany\x1a)company_package/project_package/foo.proto\" \n\x03\x42\x61r\x12\x19\n\x03\x66oo\x18\x01 \x02(\x0b\x32\x0c.company.Foo')
     23   ,
---> 24   dependencies=[company_package.project_package.foo_pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
     25 _sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)
     26~

AttributeError: module 'company_package' has no attribute 'project_package'
```

For the record, I've seen the infamous Protobuf/Python 3 issue post on GitHub, and I'm somewhat certain that it is not the same [problem](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1491).

My main question is: why doesn't this work? This seems like one of the simplest use-cases for protobuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was using an old version of the protoc compiler. You can download the latest version on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.0).

Here is my version information now that the issue is resolved:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.5.0
$ pip show protobuf
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.5.0.post1
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Author-email: protobuf@googlegroups.com
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: {omitted}/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: six, setuptools
```